# Laravel save() not defined

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to convert my existing insert methods into query scopes so that I can reuse them and have a more DRY approach.

This is what I want to convert into a Larvel query scope:

```
$time = new Time;
$time->employee_id  = $input['user_id'];
$time->day          = Carbon::now()->toDateString();
$time->clock_in     = Carbon::now()->toTimeString();
$time->save();
```

This is what I have now for the query scope:

```
public function scopeClockIn($query, $userID) {
    $query->employee_id  = $userID;
    $query->day          = Carbon::now()->toDateString();
    $query->clock_in     = Carbon::now()->toTimeString();
    $query->save();
}
```

This is how I am calling the above query scope:

```
$time = Time::clockIn($input['user_id']);
```

But I get the error:

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::save()
```

I have also tried:

```
$time = new Time::clockIn($input['user_id']);
```

but when I try with the `new` keyword I get an error:

`syntax error, unexpected 'clockIn' (T_STRING), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) or '$'`

Google has not been very helpful I have found other questions with the same error message but they are trying to retrieve results not insert them. Hoping someone here can help me figure out what I did wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good and well written question.

Laravel uses the **Builder** to interact with the database by e.g. constructing and executing SQL queries. Once it's done, it returns your **Time** object - or a **Collection** of them.

When you do e.g. `Time::all()` or `Time::where('something', '=', 'something')->get()`, you're not using a **Time** object but rather the **Builder**.

Scopes are applied during the "getting and returning stuff from the database" phase, this is why you're getting an error from the **Builder**. You can't save anything - because you're still constructing a query, you're not actually in an instance of a **Time** object.

---

Your thinking is good, it's generally a good idea to make things smaller and more distinct. It just shouldn't be a scope. What you want to do is probably to supply only the user id and make it a static function. Something like this:

```
public static function createFromUserId($userID) {
    $time = new static();
    $time->employee_id = $userID;
    $time->day         = Carbon::now()->toDateString();
    $time->clock_in    = Carbon::now()->toTimeString();
    $time->save();
    return $time;
}
```

Notice the `static` keyword, which means that you're not using a specific object but rather a general function on the class. That's why you get the syntax error later in your question: the `::` in `Time::clockIn()` signals that it's a static method, but you haven't made the method static.

I also made sure the method returns the created time, in case you need to do something with it. Now you can create new **Time** objects from a user id simply like this:

```
$time = Time::createFromUserId($userID);
```

I hope that answers your question.